# Default background color for pressed item in ListView / GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, background, resources

I need the **default** light-blue color for pressed items in ListView or GridView.
`view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ListSelector drawable in your layout xml:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:listSelector="#ff0000"
/>
```

or by calling:

```
yourList.setSelector(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a selectable GridView. So I need the default color for this (when you click on item it should stay selected). I just need the default color for pressed items (like the blue in listview).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.yourcolor);
```

Comment: I want the default system color for pressed items..